# gzuncompress data compressed by java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream

Tags: java, php, compression

So I'm having trouble decompressing an array of numbers which where originally compressed by the java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream method in java.

I know I am doing something wrong, as the output after decompressing is similar to this (but a lot longer):

```
string '�������?�����!�A��������������������'
```

When reading the [gzuncompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) PHP documentation on the matter I see that it says:

> "This function uncompress a compressed string."

I am totally misinterpreting the use of this function? or can it be used to decompress more than just a single string? I would really appreciate some help on this, as I don't feel like I am getting anywhere after some pretty deep searching on the subject.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think you definitely are misinterpreting *something*:

`java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream` is a class not a method, and it is an uncompressor not a compressor.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) says:

> "*This class implements a stream filter for **uncompressing** data in the **"deflate" compression format**.*"

If you are going to uncompress using `gzuncompress` at the PHP end, you need to compress using `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` at the Java end.

---

If you are going to use `java.util.zip.InflaterOutputStream` to compress at the Java end, I think you need to use `zlib.inflate` at the PHP end to uncompress it - see http://php.net/manual/en/filters.compression.php

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply, do you know if there is an equivalent to InflaterInputStream at the PHP end for decompression?